# TFS 2010 list folders that user has enough permissions

Tags: user-permissions

Is it possible in tfs 2010 to get all list of folders and files of project that user has enough permission to read (for example)?

Not sure that it's possble at all =)

Thx a lot for any help!

Comment: Is that all files and folders from the project source control root? I take it your codebase is quite small?

Comment: The Attrice TFS SideKick tool is able to show such a list, so I guess it is available through the TFS API

Comment: Yes, all files and folders from the project source control. Will have a look at Attrice TFS SideKick, thx!

Comment: Attrice TFS SideKick has 3.0 version for tfs 2010, which doesn't conatains permission sidekick =) They promise to add it on the later release.